# Cannot connect to the external ip of the k8s service

Tags: kubernetes, port

I have the following service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hedgehog
  labels:
    run: hedgehog
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    protocol: TCP
    name: restful
  - port: 8982
    protocol: TCP
    name: websocket
  selector:
    run: hedgehog
  externalIPs:
    - 1.2.4.120
```

In which I have specified an externalIP.
I'm also seeing this IP under EXTERNAL-IP when running `kubectl get services`.
However, when I do `curl http://1.2.4.120:3000` I get a timeout. However the app is supposed to give me a response because the jar running inside the container in the deployment does respond to localhost:3000 requests when run locally.

Comment: which type service is this is it LoadBalancer ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to understand you cannot place any random address in your `ExternalIP` field. Those addresses are not managed by Kubernetes and are the responsibility of the cluster administrator or you. External IP addresses specified with `externalIPs` are different than the external IP address assigned to a service of type `LoadBalancer` by a cloud provider.

I [checked the address](https://dnschecker.org/ip-whois-lookup.php?query=1.2.4.120) that you mentioned in the question and it does not look like it belongs to you. That why I suspect that you placed a random one there.

The same address appears in this [article](https://medium.com/swlh/kubernetes-external-ip-service-type-5e5e9ad62fcd) about  `ExternalIP`. As you can see here the address in this case are the IP addresses of the nodes that Kubernetes runs on.
This is potential issue in your case.

Another one is too verify if your application is listening on `localhost` or `0.0.0.0`. If it's really localhost then this might be another potential problem for you. You can change where the server process is listening. You do this by listening on `0.0.0.0`, which means “listen on all interfaces”.

Lastly please verify that your selector/ports of the services are correct and that you have at least one [endpoint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-have-any-endpoints) that backs your service.

Answer (score 0):

if you see the type of your service might be `cluster IP` try changing the type to `LoadBalancer`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: http-service
spec:
  clusterIP: 172.30.163.110
  externalIPs:
  - 192.168.132.253
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: highport
    nodePort: 31903
    port: 30102
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 30102
  selector:
    app: web
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

something like this where `type: LoadBalancer`.